# Bytes count in UTF-16 strings

Tags: java, character-encoding, utf-16

Why does UTF-16 string of 2 characters take only 6 bytes in memory, while UTF-16 string of 1 character takes 4 bytes?

Here's a SSCCE in java to demonstrate this behavior:

```
public class UTF16Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("A".getBytes("UTF-16").length);
        System.out.println("AB".getBytes("UTF-16").length);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
4
6
```

Comment: To satisfy my curiosity, please also do: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString("AB".getBytes("UTF-16")));' Thanks

Comment: nevermind, I did it myself: `[-2, -1, 0, 65, 0, 66]` - yes, byte-order-marks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to take in to consideration the 2-byte [Byte-Order-Marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) for UTF-16?

Your first 2 bytes will be either: `FE FF` or `FF FE` depending on whether you are on Big or Little endian machine. You should check...

I did, and it's `[-2, -1, 0, 65, 0, 66]`.

You should also consider that the String values do not take this extra space in memory, only when the String is encoded as `byte[]` will the byte-order-mark be added.... The String `AB` will use `char[2]` in memory until it is byte-encoded as `byte[6]`.

Comment: Updated some of the detils. Note the comment that the byte[] values you see are not the same as what's stored in memory.